# How to check if a vector contains any missing values in C++

Tags: c++, numpy, vector

I just started learning C++ and came across a problem to convert a `vector` to a numpy array using this function:

```
template<typename T>
static PyObject* vector_to_nparray(const std::vector<T>& vec, int type_num)
{
   if( !vec.empty() ) 
    {
       npy_intp dims = static_cast<npy_intp>(vec.size()); 
       PyArrayObject* vec_array = (PyArrayObject *) PyArray_SimpleNew(1, &dims, type_num);
       T *vec_array_pointer = (T*) PyArray_DATA(vec_array);

       copy(vec.begin(),vec.end(),vec_array_pointer);
       return (PyObject*) vec_array;
   } 
   else 
   {
        npy_intp dims[1] = {0};
        return (PyObject*) PyArray_ZEROS(1, dims, PyArray_FLOAT, 0);
   }
}
```

Before this conversion, I need to check if there are any missing values like `nan` or `null` in some vectors such as `std::vector<int>`. My purpose is to add the numpy array into a dataframe, but pandas will give weired values if the array column contains `NaN`.

I know I can iterate these vectors and check by `isnan(elem)` in C++, but it would be time-consuming if the vector is extremely large. I wonder if there is any quicker and smarter way to do it.

Comment: You cannot do this, because an `int` cannot be NaN nor null. But anyway, there is no "smarter" way. If you need to remove an element from a vector, you need to remove it...

Comment: @Jabberwocky But if I convert `vector<double>` to np array, pandas dataframe will show normal NaN values. What could be the problem?

Comment: `double` can be NaN, but cannot be null.  `int` cannot be NaN nor null.

Comment: There is no shortcut to testing every element of an array to discover if one or more of them has specific attributes. Although you can use parallel versions of such algorithms if you have particularly large arrays.